# Scattering of waves in a symmetrical potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, scattering

I'm looking at scattering of waves in a symmetrical potential as part of a research project.

Part of the project requires the computation of  $n_\ell(\infty)$ numerically for $k = 0.05$ and $k = 0.5$.

I'm not sure how to compute this. I will be coding the problem at a later date but I am looking to first understand how I should approach it using pen and paper!

From my research I have defined $n_\ell= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n_{\ell}(r)$,

**At $r=R$** we have;
 $\tan(n_{\ell}(R))=\frac{j_{\ell}(kR)}{y_{\ell}(kR)}$

where $y_{\ell}$ and $j_{\ell}$ are spherical Bessel functions of order $\ell$ and $R=7.0$.

If anyone could explain how I should approach this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The question needs further specifications. Your potential is "symmetrical", but kind of symmetry (V(-r)=V(r))? Moreover, if it's about electron waves (you should also specify this) you 'll have to solve Schroedinger's equation (and take the symmetry of the potential and the dimensionality of the problem take into account).

Comment: My question relates to a potential of the form $V(r)=\frac{A^2}{r^4}$. I am investigating the scattering of a $He^3$ atom by an ion.

Comment: put the potential in the radial SRE and try to solve it. On wikipedia there plenty of tricks how to do such a thing.

Comment: There are still many things which are not clear. You should think about these, this already brings you closer to the solution. Are sure about : $ n_l =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n_l(r)$? I guess it is $ n_l =\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty} n_l(r)$. And what is $R$ ??

Comment: Or look in the script of your supervisor. Nobody would give you a research project if (s)he  did not provide the tools for it.